# webstorm react scss modules unresolved variable

Tags: reactjs, scss, модули, webstorm

Подскажите как избавиться от "ошибки" в названии класса в webstorm? Используются scss модули в react. Название класса className={styles.class} не вызывает ошибки. Но название  className={styles.class__too} всегда подчёркивается как unresolved variable и не находится в scss, то есть на этот класс нельзя перейти при клике по нему. Искал в гугле, но ничего не нашёл, что бы помогло решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, никакого решения на данный момент не существует.  Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-35215](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35215); пока я могу только предложить запретить проверку, чтобы избавиться от ошибки:

```
 // noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
        return (
            <div className={styles.parent__child}>
```

см. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.3/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-in-editor